# Where can I find the sql file after mysqldump

Tags: cpanel, mysql

I have successfully connected using ssh and inputted the right credentials. Where can I find the backup sql file? Thanks in advance

Comment: run `pwd` on the remote machine to see where `mysqldump` file resides.

Comment: can I access it on my personal computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected to the remote server, take the dump of the database using following command

```
mysqldump -R -h root -u username -ppassword databasename > /home/krishna/databasename.sql;
```

Then you can able to find your database in the **/home/krishna/** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pwd` on the remote machine to see where mysqldump file resides. You can transfer it to your personal computer using scp as,

```
scp $PWD/dumpfile localuser@localhostip:/home/localuser
```

This command will prompt for local pc password, enter it. And the file will be copied to your home folder on local machine.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. Just to clarify "dumpfile" is the file I backuped right then afterwards I type the whole thing?

Comment: yes.. the remote machine must be a linux machine.. if so, do `man scp` on terminal and read about it.

Comment: What do I put in localuser and localhostip?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have logged in report server through SSH so you will get your MySQLdump file in your SSH user home directory. If you want to download that file on your local pc. Login through FTP with same SSH user details and download it

Comment: Are you talking about sftp? SSH uses port 22 and sftp uses port 21? How is that gonna work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for the answers! I consolidated all of it and came up with my own. I used mysqldump with the command line that you guys suggested and made a back up. Then I used ftp to gain access to the server's folders. That's where I downloaded the file. Again Thank you all so much